# Pin It Button is appearing in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, pinterest

I'm new to web development and I'm working on a Wordpress Theme. I'm having a very annoying issue.

The issue can be replicated by installing the Pin It Button for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-it-button/gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic?hl=en) and visiting this page.

http://shotbybauer.wilderland.co/fashion/

When you scroll to the right and hover over the images with your mouse, several new scrollbars appear. It looks like the pin it button is not scrolling with the div. When I disable the Pin It extension the problem goes away.

Why is this happening??

Comment: I dont see anything like your describe at that link???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is a bug in the `Pinterest` Button.

The cause of the scrollbars are being caused by the button which is a `<span>` that gets a left value off the view context of your page.  The Pinterest `<span>` button is setting itself to `position: absolute` on your page.

**UPDATE :**

Like **[@homerjam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050862/homerjam)** says in the comments:

> Add `<meta name="pinterest" content="nohover"></meta>` to the `<head>` of your HTML.
>
> More informations here: [Pinterest widget API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/?).

Comment: I would like to know how to solve the problem, but I only asked for an explanation of why it's happening so this is the correct answer.

Comment: @JoeBauer I had a similar problem. It was due to the css property `overflow` being set on a parent element of the image, this caused the extension to mis-calculate the image elements's offset.

Comment: @Homer did you find a way to eliminate the issue? I think you're right about why it's happening.

Comment: @JoeBauer I disabled the buttons entirely using the instructions [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/extension_faq/), which say to add `<meta name="pinterest" content="nohover"></meta>` to the `<head>` of your HTML. You can also disable per-image using `<img src="mything.jpg" data-pin-no-hover="true" />`. The only other way around this would be to lobby Pinterest to fix there extension by basing the offset on the element's `scrollParent` rthaer than the `document`.

Comment: @Homer that's too bad. I figured that's probably what you did, and that is what I ended up doing to, but I was hoping for a more ideal solution. Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score -1):

You are using a chrome extension; Since I am using FireFox I do not see the pin it button at all.

Most likely the problem you are experiencing is just the chrome extension itself (maybe a bug), nothing to do with the WordPress theme.